# wait for page to load data before rending

Tags: reactjs

I have a `useEffect` which sets state data. I want to the state (jiraticketdata) to load first before the page renders. The page is currently rendering the div which does not have the jiraticket data so I assume that the data has not been loaded yet.

Here is my Code:

```
import React, { useContext, useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { LoadingContext } from '../../../context/loading-context'
import { SnackbarContext } from '../../../context/snackbar-context'
import { UserContext } from '../../../context/user-context'
import {get} from '../../../functions/Rest'
import { Pie } from 'react-chartjs-2'


const defects = () => {
    const loading = useContext(LoadingContext)
    const snackbar = useContext(SnackbarContext)
    const user = useContext(UserContext)

    const [jiraticketsData, setJiraTicketsData] = useState('')

    useEffect(() => {
        async function onLoadJiraTicketData() {
          loading.setLoading(true)
          const results = get(`get_jira_tickets`, user.user)
          if (results.status === 0) {
              setJiraTicketsData(results.data)
          } else if (results.status >=20 && results.status <=30){
            snackbar.statusCheck(results)
            user.setSessionTokenMatches(false)
          } else snackbar.statusCheck(results)
            loading.setLoading(false)
        }
        onLoadJiraTicketData()

      }, [])


  return (!jiraticketsData ? <div>does not have jiraticketsData</div> :
    <div className="jiraTicketChart" >
      <Pie data={jiraticketsData.pie_chart}/>
    </div>

  )
}


export default defects
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React fetch data in server before render](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30929679/react-fetch-data-in-server-before-render)

Answer (score 0):

You need to move the async function outside of your use effect.